# Inversion of $2 \times 2$ block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices, schur-complement

$$X=\left(\matrix{A & B\\C & D}\right)$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are all $n \times n$ matrices. Assuming that all stated inverses exist, show that

$$X^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}&(C-DB^{-1}A)^{-1}\\(B-AC^{-1}D)^{-1}&(D-CA^{-1}B)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$

---

It has something to do with Schur complements. But all I can think of is to prove that each element of $X^{-1}$ is the same as the standard block inverse formula but when I do that I keep running back around in circles as this formula contains one of the stated inverses.
Any help would be great, thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1):

The top left block can be obtained as a [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). The other blocks can be obtained by considering $J(XJ)^{-1}$ (bottom left), $(JX)^{-1}J$ (top right) and $J(JXJ)^{-1}J$ (bottom right), where $J=\pmatrix{0&I\\ I&0}$. For instance, using the result that the top left block of $X^{-1}$ is $(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$, we have
$$X^{-1}=J(XJ)^{-1}=J\pmatrix{B&A\\ D&C}^{-1}=J\pmatrix{(B-AC^{-1}D)^{-1}&\ast \\ \ast&\ast}=\pmatrix{\ast&\ast \\ (B-AC^{-1}D)^{-1}&\ast}.$$